# Changing and loading an iframes src when the link within a file changes/updates

Tags: java, php, html, jquery, dom

I'm building a page called live_link_frame.php and within it is loading an iframe via a url pulled from a local file: live_link.txt:

```
<?php
$filePath = 'live_link.txt';
$handle = @fopen($filePath, "r");
$text = fread($handle,filesize($filePath));
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL,$text);
$live_link = reset($lines);
?>
```

and

```
<iframe src="<?php echo "$live_link"; ?>"></iframe>
```

Is there a way to have the iframe src= update with the new value from $live_link when the url is changed in the local file? It doesn't have to be isolated to just php.

Everything I've tried so far ends up being some kind of looping method and causes the live_link_frame.php page to never fully load.

Comment: I'm still a bit hazy on the requirements of this one. How is `live_link.php` content changing? Why are you reading from a php file as if it were a text file?

Comment: I have a separate program that changes the url in that file. It's a link/url on the first line with no other contents.

Comment: I updated the OP so that it says .txt if it makes it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with Javascript:

In your index page, you have some javascript that periodically checks inside `live_link.php`. You change the value in the `makeInterval` function to how often you want the file to be checked, 10000 = 10 seconds.

```
<script>
function makeInterval()
{
    getFileAndSetIframe();

    let interval = setInterval(getFileAndSetIframe, 10000);
}

function getFileAndSetIframe()
{
    let current_src = document.getElementById('changeme').getAttribute('src');
    let link = fetch('live_link.php')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then((response) => {
            if (response !== current_src) {
                document.getElementById('changeme').setAttribute('src', response);
            }
        });
}

window.addEventListener ? window.addEventListener("load",makeInterval,false) : window.attachEvent && window.attachEvent("onload",makeInterval);
</script>

<h1>This is my page</h1>

<iframe src="" id="changeme"></iframe>
```

Note that if the URLS are of external sites you will probably run into issues.

Comment: Thank you for this! This works really well. Is there any way to "reload" the iframe only when a new url is added to the live_link.php file?

Comment: Good idea, I've updated. Please mark the answer as accepted if you found it answered your question :)

Comment: Accepted Answer. Working further in my project, is it easy to implement a check against an additional file? So the script reload fires when either page "A" or page "B" changes?

Comment: I would still want the reload to be from the link inside live_link.php file. Just basically doing another file change check against a different file.